# Terminal session message: unable to find PtrFeedbackClass -- Ubuntu Mate 15.04

Tags: command-line, 15.04, mate, xinput

Running a fairly stock install of Ubuntu Mate 15.04 the following message started showing up each time I open a terminal session:

[image: PtrFeedbackClass terminal message]

Here is some xinput output:

```
unable to find PtrFeedbackClass for '9'
[19:28] robertm -- /home/robertm $ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:1028   id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]


[19:28] robertm -- /home/robertm $ xinput get-feedbacks 9
1 feedback class
KbdFeedbackClass id=0
    click is 0
    percent is 50
    pitch is 400
    duration is 100
    led_mask is 2
    global_auto_repeat is 1
[19:28] robertm -- /home/robertm $
```

It might have something to do with my keyboard but I haven't a clue what the real issue is? Any ideas? I don't have any other issues with the installed system.

Answer (score 1):

Found a stray line in the `.bashrc` file referencing a recently decommissioned mouse. Thanks to the Ubuntu Mate clan over on Google Plus.